# Calculating subtotals between two occurrences in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a column with numeric values and another column with "checkpoint" indications (marked by the value "x") where a subtotal is needed. This subtotal needs to sum the numeric values since the last occurrence of "x".

```
| Amount | Checkpoints | Total Used |
|--------|-------------|------------|
| 8      |             |            |
| 10     |             |            |
| 5      | x           | 18         |
| 11     |             |            |
| 3      | x           | 16         |
| 7      |             |            |
| 12     |             |            |
| 9      | x           | 22         |
```

Notice there can be any number of values to sum between two checkpoints and the value of the checkpoint row itself is not included. For example, the first subtotal takes the first and second values, so 8+10=18.

I'm looking for a combination of functions that will calculate the subtotals, either in Excel or Google Sheets.

[Example of worksheet before adding subtotals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lkll.png)

[Example after adding subtotals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Ywx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `C3`, use the following formula:

```
=IF(B3="x",SUM(A$2:A2)-SUM(C$2:C2),"")
```

And populate down

[image]